# Tag markdown links to the question list, but the help claims it links to the tag info

Tags: discussion, tags, markdown, site-faq, editing-help

The [faq#tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tags) says

> The tag will automatically be linked to the corresponding tag info page.

But in a question I saw today on MSO gave tag-reference to [symfony-2.0](/questions/tagged/symfony-2.0) SO tag, which was not linked to the tag info page, but to a page that has questions tagged by the given tag.

Screenshot below for reference.

[image: Tag link]

I see some discrepancy between the Faq help and actual functionality.

Is that if we link to a tag on SO(i.e. cross child SE sites), it get's linked to a page with 'questions tagged by the tag' ? or should they link to the tag wiki page for that particular tag? If it is the former then the faq needs to add this info.

One more question, is there any way to include such a tag in SO post that is linked to 'questions taggged by the tag` and having the look and feel of a tag?

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag links point to the questions having this tag - this is how it used to work from the very beginning as far as I know.

So looks like the Markdown Editing Help page contains misleading information indeed and it should be changed.

Comment: This should be the case for just MSO? or all the child SE sites? Linking to the tag wiki page is good I guess.

Comment: On each site `[tag:tag-name-here]` will link to the question having this tag on the site itself.

Comment: Correct. Verified. Thanks. Just the faq page needs to be updated then.

Comment: How to keep track of this feature request? I should come to this post again to check it this has been completed?

Comment: First change the discussion tag to feature request then moderator or developer will have to actually do the change, then he'll add [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: Well, it's still not fixed...

Comment: @Deduplicator probably because nobody asked to fix it yet, feel free to start new bug report explaining the problem and hopefully the team will see and fix.